# Representable cohomology theories in motivic homotopy theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, cohomology, motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

I am reading Mazza's, Voevodsky's and Weibel's book *Lecture Notes on Motivic Cohomology* and have grown curious about the following question:

**Which cohomology theories on $Sm/k$ are representable, i.e. appear as Hom-groups, in Voevodsky's construction of $DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}(k, R)$?**

If we let $X$ be a scheme of finite type over $k$ and $R$ a commutative unital ring, then we have (by construction) motivic homology with coefficients in $R$
$$H_{n,i}(X, R) = \text{Hom}_{DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}}(R(i)[n], R_{\text{tr}}(X)),$$
and motivic cohomology
$$H^{n,i}(X, R) = \text{Hom}_{DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}}(R_{\text{tr}}(X), R(i)[n]).$$
From this, we obtain the algebraic singular homology (and hence Suslin's singular homology) as
$$H^{\text{sing}}_n(X,R) \cong H_{n,0}(X,R)$$
and, if $X$ is a smooth separated scheme of finite type over some perfect field $k$, the higher Chow groups
$$CH^q(X, 2q-p) = H^{p,q}(X,\mathbb{Z}).$$

It is clear to me that such cohomology theories must satisfy certain properties:

- Mayer-Vietories
- $\mathbb{A}^1$-invarience
- Künneth-theorem
- ...

But do we have any other examples of cohomology theories that appear as Hom-groups in $DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}(k, R)$? How about

- Betti cohomology?
- $l$-adic cohomology?
- Crystalline cohomology?
- Algebraic de Rham cohomology?

Another way of framing the question is: How far off is Voevodsky's-Morel's $DM_{\text{Nis}}^{eff,-}(k, R)$ construction from being the category of pure/mixed motives in the sense of Grothendieck.

(I realize this might be a very hard question to which not much is known.)

Comment: Another "obvious" requirement is that the cohomology theory must have Voevodsky transfers (i.e. factor through the category $\operatorname{Corr}_k$ of Voevodsky correspondences).

Answer (score 5):

Recall that $\mathrm{DM}(k)$ can be described as the subcategory of $\mathrm{SH}(k)$ made of modules over the motivic cohomology. This implies that cohomologies which are representable in $\mathrm{DM}(k)$ receive a cycle class map, so they must admit additive Chern classes ($c_1(L\otimes L')=c_1(L)+c_1(L')$). In fact, I think this is an if and only if, in the sense that motivic cohomology is the universal among cohomologies with additive Chern classes, but I do not know right now if this is written anywhere in the motivic setting with integral coefficients. In any case, if you put $R=\mathbb{Q}$ then you can have any type of Chern classes, for example $K$-theory. This is all written at Cisinki-Déglise's [Triangulated categories...](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030332419), chapter 14, which is in general a great reference for many motivic results up until 2009.

Your question is more natural for $\mathrm{SH}(k)$, as it happens already in topology, and then you know your cohomology would belong to $\mathrm{DM}(k)$ depending  on if it is a module over motivic cohomology or not. An answer to your question in the setting of $\mathrm{SH}$ is in the paper of Cisinski and Déglise, [Mixed Weil cohomologies](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870811003823), at 2.1.5. Loosely speaking, for any "sheaf cohomology" they construct an object of $\mathrm{SH}(k)$  representing such cohomology. Their hypothesis must imply having additive Chern classes, since they are willing to define a mixed variant of Weil cohomologies (which have additive Chern classes), so their cohomologies are in $\mathrm{DM}(k)$. At the end of the paper you have their main examples.

I recall that Cisinski-Déglise's method was later rewritten and developped by Holmsotrom-Scholbach in [Arakelov motivic cohomology](https://www.ams.org/journals/jag/2015-24-04/S1056-3911-2015-00648-8/), section 3, to represent the Deligne cohomology, and by Déglise-Mazzari in [The rigid syntomic spectrum](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-institute-of-mathematics-of-jussieu/article/abs/rigid-syntomic-ring-spectrum/F7CC2419296F69BF10AB77A1FB43B21C) at 1.4.10 where they proved that the rygid syntomic cohomology is representable.

Comment: $DM$ is absolutely *not* a full subcategory of $SH$. It is, as you correctly mention, a category of modules.

Comment: Shame on me! ^_^' Thanks a lot for pointing out my mistake